# Morgan and a String HackerRank

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I'm trying the Morgan and a String challenge in hackerrank
(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/morgan-and-a-string/)

My attempt is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<testCases; i++){
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(in.next());
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(in.next());
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int indexA = 0;
            int indexB = 0;
            while(indexA < a.length() && indexB < b.length()){
                if(a.charAt(indexA)<=b.charAt(indexB)){
                    result.append(a.charAt(indexA));
                    indexA++;
                }
                else{
                    result.append(b.charAt(indexB));
                    indexB++;
                }
            }
            if(indexA==a.length()){
                result.append(b.substring(indexB,b.length()));
            }
            else{
                result.append(a.substring(indexA,a.length()));
            }
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }

    }
```

I'm getting the first two cases correctly:

2
JACK
DANIEL
ABACABA
ABACABA

Output:

DAJACKNIEL
AABABACABACABA

I'm not quite sure if I am not understanding the problem correctly or maybe I'm getting an overflow with large input cases, I cannot see the other test cases but hope you guys can take a look at the code.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think, the problem occurs when you have the same letter on top of both stacks: you cannot choose arbitrarily (which you do by always choosing the first or *a* stack), but have to compare the next letters on both stacks (and if they are equal, too, the ones after that and so on), so that you can ensure the optimal continuation...

E.g.

```
input: bbb bba

your output: bbbbba
correct output: bbabbb
```

Comment: Oh! your statement seems correct and it is very clear with the example, I will try to solve that problem. It does not look quite easy though.

Comment: If they were easy, it would be no fun solving them ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
    import java.util.ArrayDeque;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Stack;
    public class MorganStack2 {
    static String morganAndString(String a, String b) {


    char[] a1 = a.toCharArray();
    char[] b1 = b.toCharArray();


    ArrayList<Character> s1 = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayDeque<Character> jackStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    ArrayDeque<Character> danielStack = new ArrayDeque<>();


    for (int i = a1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        jackStack.push(a1[i]);

    }

    for (int i = b1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        danielStack.push(b1[i]);
    }


    int min = Math.min(a1.length, b1.length);
    int max = Math.max(a1.length, b1.length);

    int jack = 0;
    int daniel = 0;

    int c = 0;
    while (!(jackStack.isEmpty() || danielStack.isEmpty())) {
        if (jackStack.peek() < danielStack.peek()) {
            s1.add(jackStack.pop());
            jack++;
        } else if (jackStack.peek() > danielStack.peek()) {
            s1.add(danielStack.pop());
            daniel++;

        } else {
                if (a.substring(jack).compareTo(b.substring(daniel))>0){
                    s1.add(danielStack.pop());
                    daniel++;
                }else if (a.substring(jack).compareTo(b.substring(daniel))<0) 
                  {
                    s1.add(jackStack.pop());
                    jack++;
                }else{
                    if(a.compareTo(b)>=0){
                        s1.add(danielStack.pop());
                        daniel++;

                    }else  if(a.compareTo(b)<0){
                        s1.add(jackStack.pop());
                        jack++;

                    }else{
                        System.out.println("hyy");
                    }
                }


            }
            c++;
        }
      }
        // System.out.println(c);         AAAAAAAAAA
        //System.out.println(max);
        // System.out.println(min);
        if (jackStack.isEmpty()) {
            while (!danielStack.isEmpty()) {
                s1.add(danielStack.pop());
            }
        } else {
            while (!jackStack.isEmpty()) {
                s1.add(jackStack.pop());
            }
        }


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Character s : s1) {
            sb.append(s);

        }


        return sb.toString();
    }



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

    int t = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    for (int tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
        String a = scanner.nextLine();

        String b = scanner.nextLine();

        String result = morganAndString(a, b);
        System.out.println(result);


       }



       scanner.close();
      }


  }
```