# Selecting next lexicographical shortest element

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Jack and Daniel are friends. Both of them like letters, especially upper-case ones. 
They are cutting upper-case letters from newspapers, and each one of them has their collection of letters stored in separate stacks. 
One beautiful day, Morgan visited Jack and Daniel. He saw their collections. Morgan wondered what is the lexicographically minimal string, made of that two collections. He can take a letter from a collection when it is on the top of the stack. 
Also, Morgan wants to use all the letters in the boys' collections.

**Input Format**

The first line contains the number of test cases,t . 
Every next two lines have such format: the first line contains string a, and the second line contains string b.

**Output the lexicographically minimal string  for each test case in new line.**

**Sample Input**

2

JACK

DANIEL

ABACABA

ABACABA

**Sample Output**

DAJACKNIEL

AABABACABACABA

Here is my approach:

```
t = int(raw_input())
for _ in range(t):
    a = raw_input()
    b = raw_input()
    i = 0
    j = 0
    prev = 0
    res = ""
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i:] < b[j:]:
            res += a[i]
            i += 1
            prev = 0
        elif a[i:] > b[j:]:
            res += b[j]
            j += 1
            prev = 1
        else:
            if prev == 0:
                res += a[i]
                i += 1
                prev = 0
            else: 
                res += b[j]
                j += 1
                prev = 1
    print res + a[i:]+b[j:]
```

Comment: What is the problem with your _approach_? What have you tried so far to solve the issue you are facing?

Comment: Is there an actual question here, or just a homework problem?

Comment: I am able to clear the above two test cases, but when i tried to do these test cases it starts to fail
2
BBBABA
BBBABB
BBBABB
BBBABA
Is there something wrong with the logic that i have applied? , No this isnt a homework problem, I am just practising string quesions and am unable to get this one done. THanks @ilim

Comment: For BBBABA BBBABB your program prints BBBABABBBABB. Isn't it the right answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46373849/1566221

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Morgan and a String HackerRank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927873/morgan-and-a-string-hackerrank)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case when `a = "C"` and `b = "CA"`. Your program's output will be `"CCA"` but the right answer is `"CAC"`. The problem is that your code prefers `"C"` over `"CA"` because `"C" < "CA"`.